# Horizontal line in Gadfly

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

I am using [Gadfly.jl](https://github.com/GiovineItalia/Gadfly.jl) in order to plot my function. I try to add a horizontal line by passing the `Geom.hline` argument. However, I am getting an error:

> Couldn't process recipe args: (typeof(f), Int64, Float64,
>   Gadfly.Geom.HLineGeometry)

What am I missing?

Here is my code

```
using Gadfly

f(x)=x/(1-x)

plot(f,0,0.8, yintercept=1.5,  Geom.hline(style=:dot))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `yintercept` aesthetics accepts only an array of values:

```
plot(f,0,0.8, yintercept=[1.5], Geom.hline(style=:dot))
```